# turn small double to int

Tags: c++, terrain

I'm using [libnoise](http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/index.html) to generate 2D sprite forrests. [image]

Then I made my world larger, I am currently working within world 1.0 to -1.0. The problem now is that I can no longer generate the few pixels the trees are offset by (from their grid positions). So they are not all in rows. I used to take the noise value and when I placed a tree I would then multiply the noise value with an int to make it larger and modulus it to get a random deviation that was the same every-time in that point in the world.

```
// offset each forest decal by a small amount for asthetic purposes
surface_xy.x = surface_x + float(FOREST::HALF_UNIT - int(perlin_noise_value * 100.0) % FOREST::UNIT);
surface_xy.y = surface_y + float(FOREST::HALF_UNIT - int(perlin_noise_value * 200.0) % FOREST::UNIT);
```

Now that my world is larger my formula which must work anywhere in the world doesn't work because the noise value is very very small. How do I get a consistent random value in pixels between say for example -5 and 5 from 1.1055228575200001e-012? Or perhaps someone knows of an alternative to using the noise value.

Comment: If you told us more about the range of `perlin_noise_value` and where you got it from, we may be able to offer a cleaner solution.

Comment: @FredOverflow `perlin_noise_value` is generated by libnoise based on the world co-ordinates defined by me. I am currently working in world co-ordinate spaces of `1.0` to `-1.0` in increments of `0.000000000000001`. The noise values I back will always be in the same range of values as my world co-ordinates i.e. you can assume double value of `0.000000000000001` and up. The noise values are the same for the same world co-ordinates and are perlin in nature. The values are suitable for how I generate my trees in clusters.

Comment: @FredOverflow I do not have to use the perlin noise values to offset my trees within my grid and I might still get other values since they are not in a suitable format. For example I might generate a separate world of noise values mapping to this world but in large number ranges rather than small doubles. Your first answer was a very good answer, I too feel like there should be a cleaner solution but I also want to keep it fast, and I think the cleaner solution might also mean a slow solution.

Comment: Just to be clear, each tree has x/y coordinates between -1.0 and +1.0, and you want to deterministically get a pseudo-random offset between -5 and +5 for each tree?

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler if the trees had pixel coordinates to begin with, like from 0 to 65535 or something? Why do you store them as -1.0 to +1.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get a consistent random value in pixels between say for example -5 and 5 from 1.1055228575200001e-012?

You could look at the internal representation of the double and combine the bits into an int:

```
int from_noise(double noise)
{
    unsigned long long bits;
    memcpy(&bits, &noise, 8);
    unsigned x = bits ^ (bits >> 32);
    return x % 11 - 5;
}
```

Note: `from_noise` assumes that `double` and `long long` take 8 bytes, and `int` takes 4 bytes. Also, the function will return different results on big-endian and little-endian architectures.

Comment: this is perfect, I had no idea what a double was in bits or how to get at those small values

Comment: why do I have to do a memcopy though, is there no way to shift then cast? or does the floating point stop me?

Comment: The `memcpy` call (or alternatively, the union trick) is necessary if you want to look at the bits of a floating point number. You cannot look at the bits by a simple cast.

Comment: Actually you can, if you have a `double x;` then you can access the bits by casting as `*((unsigned long long*)&x);`.

Comment: @DiJuMx Or even simpler `(unsigned long long&)x`, but those solutions are even less portable than the `memcpy` trick and the union hack ;) Still +1 for completeness.

Comment: I went with `int as_random_int(int((*((unsigned long long*)&perlin_noise_value)) >> 32));`

Comment: Why without the `^` part? You're throwing away half of the randomness.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you could do something like:

```
#define RANGE_MIN     (-5)
#define RANGE_MAX     (+5)
#define RESOLUTION    (1.1055228575200001e-012)
#define NUM_OF_VALUES ((int)((RANGE_MAX-RANGE_MIN)/RESOLUTION))

double GetRandVal()
{
    return rand()%NUM_OF_VALUES*RESOLUTION+RANGE_MIN;
}
```

Unfortunately, the maximum return-value of `rand()` is typically 32767, while the specified range and resolution in your example yield 9045493661191 values. So you will have to use `rand()` several times:

```
#define RANGE_MIN     (-5)
#define RANGE_MAX     (+5)
#define RESOLUTION    (1.1055228575200001e-012)
#define NUM_OF_VALUES ((unsigned long long)((RANGE_MAX-RANGE_MIN)/RESOLUTION))

int GetNumOfBits(unsigned long long val)
{
    int numOfBits = 0;
    while (val > 0)
    {
        numOfBits++;
        val >>= 1;
    }
    return numOfBits;
}

static int numOfBitsInRandMax = GetNumOfBits(RAND_MAX);
static int numOfBitsInNumVals = GetNumOfBits(NUM_OF_VALUES);
static int quotient  = numOfBitsInNumVals/numOfBitsInRandMax;
static int remainder = numOfBitsInNumVals%numOfBitsInRandMax;

double GetRandVal()
{
    unsigned long long randVal = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<quotient; i++)
        randVal = (randVal<<numOfBitsInRandMax)|rand();
    randVal = (randVal<<remainder)|(rand()&((1<<remainder)-1));
    return randVal%NUM_OF_VALUES*RESOLUTION+RANGE_MIN;
}
```

Please note however, that on the theoretical aspect, it reduces the level of true randomness.

And BTW, don't forget to seed the RNG using `srand((unsigned int)time(NULL))`...

Comment: but if i seed random with time then wont the random differ each I run it, i'm looking for the same values for the same places in the world every time. and if i don't seed it or seed it with an odd literal will i get the same values every-time?

Comment: @user3345413: If you seed the RNG with a constant value (any value), then function `rand()` will yield the same random sequence every time you run the program. Of course, if the points in the execution of your program when `rand()` is called depend on user input, then you might end up with a different result each time (or some of the times).

Comment: `surface_xy.x = surface_x + 1 - rand() % 3; surface_xy.y = surface_y + 1 - rand() % 3;` I went with this but then I realized that I would get different results depending on which area of the world I generate first. So if I seed the random number generator before I generate a part of the world with say the y value I could get the same results as long as I generate in tiles/patches?

Comment: @user3345413: As I said, if you seed the RNG with the same constant value, then function `rand()` will yield the same random sequence from that point onwards. I am not sure how your program works, so I cannot guarantee that you'll get the same results as long as you generate tiles/patches. But looking at the answer you accepted above (assuming you've accepted it because it's correct), it seems that you can simply use my solution with `noise` instead of `rand()`.

Comment: @user3345413 (continuing the comment above): The only thing that you will have to change is `RAND_MAX`. If this is not possible due to the nature of `noise` (being double or whatever), then you'll need to change the way that `numOfBitsInRandMax` is calculated (and semantically, rename `RandMax` to `NoiseMax`).

Comment: this is a nice solution but it is more than I need, I's solved the issue with a combination of everyone's advice and learnt a few new things. thank you (in the end for my case I only needed a consistent seed for the small variation in positions, the perlin noise values are just what I needed for tree formations).